# is any change in the given code so i can have correct output for the question

Tags: c++, string, oop, coding-style, error-correction

what changes I have to make in the code for correct output.

Write a C++ program to convert the first character of the string to uppercase and return the new string, if the first character of the string is already in uppercase, then return the same string.

Note:
    Use front() function to access the first character of the string
    Use toupper() function to convert to uppercase

Input and Output Format
Input and output consists of a string.
[All text in bold represents the input and remaining represents output]

Sample Input and Output 1:

```
Enter the string
nicholas
Nicholas
```

Sample Input and Output 2:

```
Enter the string
Henry
Henry
```

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void convert(string& s)
{
    for(int i=0;i++;i++){
        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter the string"<<endl;
    getline(cin,s);
    convert(s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void convert(string& s)
{
    for(int i=0;i++;i++){
    s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
}
}
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter the string"<<endl;
    getline(cin,s);
    convert(s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Where's your code? Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I added in the comment section

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please **[edit]** your question to include your attempt in the form of a [mcve], together with a detailed description of the problems you have with it (like for example sample input, the actual output and the expected output). Also please tell us what *debugging* efforts you have made.

Comment: You have to convert the first character only, not all. No need for a loop

Comment: @HayleySatjan Please [edit] your question to add the code to the question itself. In the comment section the formatting gets just messed as you see.

Comment: Edit the question!

Answer (score 2):

Using `front()` function to access the **first character of the string** and `toupper()` function to **convert to uppercase**.

```
string convert(string& s) { 
    if(islower(s.front()))
        s.front() = toupper(s.front());

    return s;
} 

int main() { 
    string s; 
    cout<<"Enter the string"<<endl; 
    getline(cin,s); 
    cout<<convert(s)<<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{

    string str = "something";
    str[0] = toupper(str[0]);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is enough to capitalize the first letter of a string, you don't need to loop through the whole string :)